# register_rest_field for custom taxonomy fields that are assosiated with custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, rest-api, endpoints

I am trying to register a rest field for my custom taxonomy's custom meta fields. I followed the tutorial at [Modifying Responses](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/) . The code worked great for adding a rest field for post meta data for custom post types, but when I tried the following code to add a rest field for my custom taxonomy, it didn't work. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_location' );

//REGISTER
function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_location() {
    register_rest_field( 'location',
        'location_code',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'location_get_term_meta',
            'update_callback' => 'location_update_term_meta',
            'schema' => null;
        )
    );
}

//WRITE
function location_update_term_meta_field( $value, $object, $field_name ) {
    if ( ! $value || ! is_string( $value ) ) {
        return;
    }
    return update_term_meta( $object->ID, $field_name, $value );
}

//READ
function location_get_term_meta_field( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_term_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}
```

Comment: Did you register your custom post type wit wp api? e.g: `'show_in_rest' => true,`

Answer (score 2):

Both callbacks in the register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_location() function are misspelled.

change

```
'get_callback'    => 'location_get_term_meta',
'update_callback' => 'location_update_term_meta',
```

to

```
'get_callback'    => 'location_get_term_meta_field',
'update_callback' => 'location_update_term_meta_field',
```

Register Code

```
function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_location() {
    register_rest_field( 'location',
        'location_code',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'location_get_term_meta_field',
            'update_callback' => 'location_update_term_meta_field',
            'schema' => null,
        )
    );
```